# Bluetooth dongles vs Wifi dongles

Tags: usb, wifi

I see a lot of implementations on how to use a bluetooth usb dongle with arduino microcontroller. But I dont see even one single implementation to use with the wifi usb dongles. I get that the stack is complex and that memory is definitely going to be a concern. But assuming I can find a MCU which has enough memory and also going on the assumption that the TCP/IP stack that I implement will be somewhat small, it would be a question of porting the underlying drivers only for the given wifi dongle. Before I get onto this project(just for the fun of it) I want to make sure that I am not missing something . Is there any implementation for a USB wifi dongle for an MCU because I wasnt able to find anything on the internet.

Second, if I plan to use the RTL8188 chip I observe that the drivers are already present in the linux source. What would be the difficulties that I would probably encounter while porting it? Also why has no one got it running succesfully?

Answer (score 1):

It all depends if you need to go ad-hoc or peer-to-peer mode (i.e. direct from the Arduino to the dongle), or use WiFi infrastructure mode via an access point.  (If you have a wireless router in your house, you already have an access point.)

In infrastructure mode, your Arduino will be assigned an IP address via DCHP from the router, and the dongle in your PC will also be assigned an IP via DHCP (or you can configure static IPs for each one if desired).  The Arduino can then connect to the dongle by specifying its IP address, and using whatever Internet protocol you need to use to carry out your task (HTTP, FTP, SSH etc.)

It is possible to get WiFi shields with the TCP/IP stack built-in (they have their own microcontroller); that way you are not tying up any memory in the Arduino's main processor.  The Arduino communicates with the shield over either UART or SPI, depending on the board.

Comment: But it is still doable correct? I want to make sure I am not just doing something which I know is not possible

Comment: Very doable.  I ran something similar on a Leopardboard (similar to a Beagleboard) a few years ago.  As long as you have a TCP/IP stack on your Arduino (either built into the WiFi board if it has its own processor, or you Arduino processor if talking to the WiFi module directly, then you can connect assign an IP address to your Arduino and get into your LAN. You can then set up any Internet protocol you wish (with the right software).  I have a Beaglebone Black, with its local IP opened up to the outside Internet, running a web server plus SSH and FTP accessible from anywhere from my iPad.

Comment: I know I can do it with a Beaglebone. I am worried as to whether I can do it on an MCU because it must have enough memory to support this stack. I see a lot of implementation of blueooth dongles with the arduino shields but none for wifi.